# Fixing the format of the answer

Tags: java

```
public static void displayBalance(double balance) {
    System.out.printf("Account balance: $%.2f", balance);
    System.out.println();
}
```

For my output I am getting this

Enter amount to withdraw: $1600

$21.940000000000055

How do I fix the problem with the format of my answer so it is only for 2 decimal places even if there are 0's there. **i am not allowed to use the DecimalFormat **

Comment: turn it into a string. Do some logic after the . or the end of the number if there is none, turn back to decimal heh.

Comment: Consider representing the amount as `BigDecimal` rather than `double`.

Comment: It is strange that you are getting that output, given that "Account balance:" does not appear in the output and that "Enter amount to withdraw:" does not appear in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have comment rep, so I have to answer.  There's nothing wrong with your code in the question.  I can pass it a number like *1d/3* and it only shows "0.33".  So I'm guessing you lost something in the translation of your code to the SO question...